# Registering and resolving dependencies in a loop

Tags: dryioc

I have the following hardcoded setup in an application using MVVM:

```
var ips = configFile.Read();

for (string ip in ips)
{
    var tcpClient = new TcpClient(ip);
    var stream = (Stream) tcpClient.GetStream();
    var service = new Service(stream);
    var connectionViewModel = new ConnectionViewModel(service);
    var extendedViewModel = new ExtendedViewModel(connectionViewModel);
}
```

A number of IP addresses are read from a file, and each address results in a ViewModel being created that displays stuff from the IP.

What is the best approach if I want to let DryIoc handle this? All `new` objects are unique foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible option is using Func to pass the ip:

```
var c = new Container();
c.Register<ExtendedViewModel>();
c.Register<ConnectionViewModel>();
c.Register<Service>();
c.Register<TcpClient>();

foreach (var ip in ips) {
    var getVM = c.Resolve<Func<string, ExtendedViewModel>>();
    var vm = getVM(ip);
    // use vm
}
```

**Update:**

For Stream, add the following registration without changing the resolution part:

```
c.Register<Stream>(Made.Of(
    _ => ServiceInfo.Of<TcpClient>(),
    tcpClient => (Stream)tcpClient.GetStream()));
```

Made.Of plays nicely with Func and other wrappers resolutions, and can be in the middle of object graph. That's why it is preferable over RegisterDelegate.

Comment: Interesting. Does this uniquely resolve all dependencies? I have added a variation of the problem with stream. Can the answer be modified to include the variation?

Comment: I have updated my answer. It resolves the rest of dependencies, not provided as Func by resolving them from container.

Comment: Thanks. I get an error `Registered Disposable Transient service TcpClient with key {no key}` on the registering of TcpClient. How should I proceed?

Comment: new Container(rules => rules.WithTrackingDisposableTransients());
https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/ReuseAndScopes#markdown-header-disposable-transient